# Is it possible to disable weak ciphers in C# programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, tls1.2, 3des

I want to disable CBC ciphers in our client application. The application is built on .NET Framework 4.7.2 and uses TLS 1.2 to connect to server.

Is there any possibility to do this without changing the registry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing .NET application to use TLS 1.2 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768631/forcing-net-application-to-use-tls-1-2-or-later)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388038/supporting-tls-1-2-in-httpclient-c-sharp Note that you _can_ also automate the modification of the Windows Registry (which some people recommend modifying the computer's settings rather than forcing the protocol in code).